# Removing duplicate entries in text file

Tags: text-processing

I am doing some sorting with `uniq -d` command. it's not getting me the desired results.

My file is like:

```
>TCONS_00000066 174     206  33
>TCONS_00000066 210     281  72
>TCONS_00000066 227     316  90
>TCONS_00000066 285     338  54
>TCONS_00000066 335     373  39
>TCONS_00000066 342     377  36
>TCONS_00006042 493     552  60
>TCONS_00006042 562     606  45
>TCONS_00006042 630     686  57
>TCONS_00006042 622     699  78
>TCONS_00006042 614     724  111
>TCONS_00006042 696     767  72
```

I want to remove duplicates in column 1

output:

```
     >TCONS_00000066
     >TCONS_00006042
```

but I get a blank file everytime I do

> uniq -d file > newfile

is there any other way?

Comment: You want to _remove_ duplicates, or _output_ duplicates? Your Question says _remove_ but your example shows _output_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use awk:

```
awk '!x[$1]++ { print $1 }' file
```

Answer (score 3):

Uniq doesn't sort and it doesn't strip the rest of the line. `uniq -d` only shows duplicated lines, which is not the same as showing each line once (i.e. with `-d` it has to be in there twice, and consecutively to be shown)

First cut the non-interesting columns, then sort and then find the unique elements:

```
cut -d ' ' -f 1 your_file | sort | uniq
```

Answer (score 2):

`uniq -d` lists only duplicated lines from its input; since your file contains no duplicate lines (considered in their entirety), it outputs nothing.

To get the result you're after, you need to extract the first column, and filter that:

```
cut -d\  -f1 file | uniq
```

assuming your file is sorted (`uniq` only filters duplicate adjacent lines); otherwise

```
cut -d\  -f1 file | sort -u
```

Or you can do it with `awk` as pointed out by [taliezin](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/102632/taliezin), with a slight variant to only output the first column:

```
awk '!x[$1]++ { print $1 }' file
```